# Return something specific in case an array's key does not exist

Tags: php, arrays, default

is there a way to make an array return the a "default value" if the requested key was not set?

Example:

```
$arr = array("a_set_key" => "A Value");
$arr = the_function_I_need($arr, "n/a");
echo $arr['any_key']; // Shall return "n/a"
echo $arr['a_set_key']; // Shall return "A Value"
```

Comment: If " if the requested key was not set" how will you check if it exists is true? That is how will your hypothetical function `the_function_I_need()` know what all the keys are? You only pass it the original array and a default value.

Comment: [`null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) - _"The special `null` value represents a variable with no value. `null` is the only possible value of type `null`."_

Comment: there is no built-in function that does that, you can however use a simple ternary

Comment: So I guess it is not possible.

Comment: It is possible, but your `the_function_I_need()` doesn't know all the possible array keys, since you don't show code or have a parameter that states it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any native way to do and use it as you want but there are other ways, the most usual is to use `isset` which you could use like this:

```
echo isset($arr['any_key']) ? $arr['any_key'] : 'n/a';
echo $arr['any_key'] ?? 'n/a'; // php 7.0+
```

Or you can create special class which act like that, for example like this:

```
class the_function_I_need implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $arr;
    private $naval;
    public function __construct($arr, $naval) {
        $this->arr = $arr;
        $this->naval = $naval;
    }
    
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->arr[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        //return isset($this->arr[$offset]) ? $arr[$offset] : $this->naval; // pre 7.0 php
        return $this->arr[$offset] ?? $this->naval; // php 7.0+
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->arr[$offset] = $value;
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->arr[$offset]);
    }
}

$arr = array("a_set_key" => "A Value");
$arr = new the_function_I_need($arr, "n/a");
echo $arr['any_key']; // Shall return "n/a"
echo $arr['a_set_key']; // Shall return "A Value"
```

Notice that the `$arr` variable is no longer an array but object.